# Laravel - Better Error Tracking

Tags: php, debugging, laravel, bug-tracking

After we have develop the web application using Laravel, we need tool for better tracking and monitoring for any possible bug & error occur. Is there any nice free tool / plugin that works well with Laravel for tracking & monitoring errors?

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- [LogViewer](https://github.com/ARCANEDEV/LogViewer) - Provides a log viewer UI, API for Laravel 5.x

> - Laravel 5.x to 9.x is supported.
> - A great Log viewer API.
> - Ready to use (Views, Routes, controllers … Out of the box) [Note: No need to publish assets]
> - View, paginate, filter, download and delete logs.
> - Load a custom logs storage path.
> - Localized log levels.
> - Logs menu/tree generator.
> - Grouped logs by dates and levels.
> - Customized log levels icons (font awesome by default).
> - Works great with big logs !!
> - Well documented package (IDE Friendly).
> - Well tested (100% code coverage with maximum code quality).

- [Laravel log viewer](https://github.com/rap2hpoutre/laravel-log-viewer) - Simple & Light weight Log viewer

> - Supports Laravel 5, 6, 7 & 8 (still compatible with 4.2 too) and Lumen.

- [LERN](https://github.com/tylercd100/lern) - LERN will record exceptions into a database and will notify you via Email, Pushover, Slack, etc.

> Laravel 5.x to 8x is supported
>
> Currently supported notification channels via Monolog
>
> Email, Pushover, Slack, Hipchat, Fleephook, Flowdock, Plivo an SMS
> messaging service, Twilio an SMS messaging service, Sentry via Raven,
> Mailgun

**Paid Services**

- [Bugsnag](https://www.bugsnag.com) -  Free version available. Focused and powerful error monitoring for web, mobile, and server apps.
- [Rollbar](https://rollbar.com) - Free version available. It provides real-time exception reporting and continuous deployment monitoring for developers.

Comment: Trying out LERN, works out of box and looks to be actively developed and updated for most recent laravel as well.

Answer (score 1):

If you are after a package to monitor your package while you are developing - you can try Clockwork: https://github.com/itsgoingd/clockwork

If you need a solution for monitoring your application in production - you can checkout [Eyewitness.io](https://eyewitness.io). It will monitor your Laravel application, and alert you if there are any problems with the website, cron schedules, queues, logs etc.

*disclaimer: I made the solution*

Answer (score 0):

Any good log monitoring tool should accomplish the goal. Laravel will put all errors into `app/storage/logs/laravel.log`. The log monitoring tool would watch that log for errors.

Answer (score 0):

I am the author of laravel [lapse](https://github.com/pyaesone17/lapse).

Unlike Logviewer, **lapse** only store the error from Exception / Throwable.

Lapse provides a beautiful dashboard to track your errors in production without having to look up log file. Moreover it can notify you via Slack channel and Email alert. And moreover it can notify you via all of the channels from [laravel notification channels](http://laravel-notification-channels.com/).

Lapse behind the scence depend on https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/notifications. It means theoretically Lapses can notify your error via over 30 ways including Slack, Email, Nexmo, Trello, Telegram, Facebook, Discord, Pusher, Twillo, Twitter.

The search and filter is very fast because **lapse** store the error stack in the database instead of working on the log file.

Answer (score -1):

Depending on which version of laravel you are using, there is this package: http://packalyst.com/packages/package/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar